# Win32gui SetCursor not working when I use win32 API

Tags: python, winapi, win32gui

I am trying to make my own library that uses windows, and when I put my cursor in the window on the edge sometimes it just keeps the cursor the same and doesn't change it.
So I tried making a function in my class called "SetCursor" which takes an argument of win32con.IDC_(CursorName) but it doesn't seem to be changing it and the issue still occurs where if I enter my mouse into the window it stays as it was when it entered the window (Example, the resize arrow cursor)

```py
def SetCursor(self, CursorType=win32con.IDC_NO):
        hCursor = win32gui.LoadCursor(0, CursorType)
        try:
            win32gui.SetCursor(hCursor)
        except TypeError:
            print('[SetCursor] Enable to set cursor, invalid PyHANDLE object.')

MyClass.SetCursor(win32con.IDC_CROSS)
```

The `MyClass.SetCursor` runs in a while loop
Image of the cursor thing:
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMbmM.png)

I was trying to make a window that can show images and rectangles but it just doesn't make the rectangles appear (That's for a separate question) and the cursor stays stuck at the one it was when it entered the window.

Comment: The cursor shape that's used when the mouse pointer is inside a window is determined by the `hCursor` field of the [`WNDCLASSEXW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw) structure when registering the window class.

Comment: @IInspectable then how could I reference an hCursor?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking *"How do I register a window class?"* instead? You apparently already know how to load a (system) cursor.

Comment: Yeah sorry I am a bit tired lol, but yeah how should I register it?

Comment: You could try to use [RegisterClass function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassa)to register a window class.

For more details, you could refer to the Doc: [Registering Window Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/registering-window-classes)

Comment: Have you got any updates? May I know if you have got any chance to check my suggestion?